# Nautilus - Missing titlebar following reboot (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: unity, nautilus, titlebar

I ran the upgrade commands that I normally do (listed below). Everything appeared to be operating normally, but I opted to do a reboot. Upon rebooting and using Nautilus, I noticed that things appeared to be different. The icons seemed larger, and I immediately noticed that the titlebar was missing.

Furthermore, the rename shortkey <kbd>F2</kbd> now brings up  a toolkit popup, where as before I don't recall ever seeing it do this. It almost looks like I was running a different file manager, and so I ran nautilus from the terminal. The results were exactly the same.

I rebooted once more, as well as logged out & logged back in. No matter what I do, the titlebar remains missing. Furthermore, the action buttons (close, minimize, maximize) appear on the right, versus the left. It almost looks like a hybrid 16.04 and 17.10 installation, since I know that the action buttons were moved in 17.10.

I'm running 16.04 LTS right now, and I'm working on Unity.

[image: ]]
[image: ]]

Commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt clean
sudo updatedb
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Does the application menu appear if you press the Alt key (with the Nautilus window focused)? Does it appear in the top panel of the Unity desktop?

Comment: @DavidFoerster It does appear in the Unity menu upon clicking Alt. I looked into the Preferences menu, and couldn't find anything related to the issues I'm experiencing.